# Async/await во vue.js firebase

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, firebase-database

Всем здравствуйте. Появилась проблема с получением данных с firebase database. При открытии страницы категорий (Category.vue), в компонент CategoryEdit передается пустой массив. Как это можно исправить?

Функция fetchCategories в category.module.js (vuex).

```
async fetchCategories({ dispatch, commit }) {
      try {
        const uid = await dispatch("auth/getUid", "", { root: true });
        const db = getDatabase();

        const categoryListRef = ref(db, `users/${uid}/categories`);
        let categoryList = [];

        onValue(categoryListRef, (snapshot) => {
          categoryList = snapshot.val();
          categoryList = Object.keys(categoryList).map((key) => ({
            id: key,
            ...categoryList[key],
          }));
          console.log(categoryList); // выводит вытянутые с firebase данные
          commit("setCategories", categoryList);
        });
        console.log(categoryList); // выводит undefined
      } catch (error) {
        // console.log(error);
        // dispatch("setMessage", error.code, { root: true });
      }
},
```

Компонент категории.

```
<template>
  <div class="page-title">
    <h3>Категории</h3>
  </div>
  <section>
    <loader v-if="loading" />
    <div class="row" v-else>
      <category-create @created="pushCategory(category)" />

      <category-edit :categories="categories" />
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import CategoryCreate from "@/components/CategoryCreate.vue";
import CategoryEdit from "@/components/CategoryEdit.vue";
import Loader from "@/components/app/Loader.vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { computed, onMounted, ref } from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    const categories = ref([]);
    const loading = ref(true);

    onMounted(async () => {
      await store.dispatch("category/fetchCategories", {
        root: true,
      });
      categories.value = computed(() => store.getters["category/categories"]);
      loading.value = false;
    });

    const pushCategory = (category) => {
      categories.value.push(category);
    };

    return {
      categories,
      loading,
      pushCategory,
    };
  },
  components: {
    CategoryCreate,
    CategoryEdit,
    Loader,
  },
};
</script>
```

Компонент редактирования категорий.

```
<template>
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <div v-if="!categories.length">
      <div class="page-subtitle">
        <h4>Категорий пока что нет. Добавьте новые категории</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <div class="page-subtitle">
        <h4>Редактировать</h4>
      </div>

      <form>
        <div class="input-field">
          <select ref="selectRef" v-model="current">
            <option v-for="c in categories" :key="c.id">
              {{ c.name }}
            </option>
            <!-- <option>Category 1</option>
            <option>Category 1</option>
            <option>Category 1</option> -->
          </select>
          <label>Выберите категорию</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="text" id="name" />
          <label for="name">Название</label>
          <span class="helper-text invalid">TITLE</span>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field">
          <input id="limit" type="number" />
          <label for="limit">Лимит</label>
          <span class="helper-text invalid">LIMIT</span>
        </div>

        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">
          Обновить
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted, watch } from "vue";
export default {
  props: ["categories"],
  setup(props) {
    const selectRef = ref(null);
    const selectMaterialize = ref(null);
    const current = ref(props.categories[0]);

    console.log(current.value);

    onMounted(() => {
      selectMaterialize.value = M.FormSelect.init(selectRef.value);
    });

    onUnmounted(() => {
      if (selectMaterialize.value && selectMaterialize.value.destroy) {
        selectMaterialize.value.destroy();
      }
    });

    watch(current, (newValue, oldValue) => {
      console.log(newValue);
      console.log(oldValue);
    });

    return {
      selectRef,
      current,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```